# Recommended data flow (import/export)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter application which (simply put) list some data on various screens and can be modified. My current data approach works, but I feel it is not a best practice or optimal.

Currently, when a object is saved, it is converted to JSON (using `dart:convert`) and stored in a file on the device (using `dart.io`), overriding the file if it exist. Every screen that needs to display these objects reads the file to get the objects. Every time there is a change that needs to be saved, it exports everything (overwrites) again then imports it again to display it.

The reason I chose JSON over S is because I want to add a web portion later. Does this approach of reading/writing a best practice? I feel this much reading/writing of all the data for most screens could cause some performance issues.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Why not keep it in-memory and write it away when changes are made to your data model?

Comment: It really depends on how much data you are writing. Do you notice any performance problems? How big to the json files get?

Comment: @kent At the moment, one object is under 1000 chars (on line). Most people will be using it around 10 or so objects at a time (so ~10,000 chars), while the maximum may be around 100 objects (100,000 chars). I have not tested performance yet, but is on my list if I am going to keep this method.

Comment: @voracious This make sense and seems obvious now. My only fear is the user closing the app and not saving, but I see I may be able to force a save if needed on close - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19594

Comment: No reason you can't keep it in ram and also save it to disk automatically when a change happens. Make sure to do the I/O on a async thread so your UI is not tied up. Most iOS apps don't explicitly ask the user to press a save button it just happens.

Comment: @NedWilbur that's one possible way, I'll post an answer later showing a different way. Maybe it'll be useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible way to keep data in-memory and write to disk when changes are made to your datamodel/settings.

I use [RxDart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) myself. You don't need it per se, although it does make life easier. I'll be simplifying the examples below, so you get to know the concept and apply it to your own needs.

Let say you keep track of data in your settings class:

```dart
@JsonSerializable()
class Settings {
    String someData1;
    String someData2;

    // json seriazable functions
}
```

You need a "handler"<sup>1</sup> or something similar that manages changes made to your `Settings` and also to read/write data:

```dart
class SettingsHandler {
    Settings _settings;
    StreamController<Settings> _settingsController = BehaviorSubject<Settings>();

    StreamController<String> _data1Controller = BehaviorSubject<String>();
    StreamSink<String> get data1Input => _data1Controller.sink;
    Observable<String> get data1Output => Observable(_data1Controller.stream);

    Future<Settings> _readFromDisk() async {
        // do your thing
    }

    Future<Settings> _writeToDisk(Settings settings) async {
        // do your thing
    }

    Future<void> init() async {
        // read from disk
        _settings = await _readFromDisk();
        _settingsController.sink.add(_settings);

        // initialize data
        data1Input.add(_settings.someData1);
        data1Output
            .skip(1) // we skip because we just added our initialization data above.
            .listen((value) =>
                // we must propagate through the update function
                // otherwise nothing gets written to disk
                update((settings) => settings.someData1 = value)
            );

        // when changes are made, it needs to notify this stream
        // so everything can be written to disk
        _settingsSaver.output
            // save settings every 2.5 seconds when changes occur.
            .debounceTime(const Duration(milliseconds: 2500))
            // get the changes and write to disk
            .listen((settings) => _writeToDisk(settings));
    }

    // this function is crucial as it allows changes to be made via the [adjustFunc]
    // and then propagates this into the _settingsSaver stream.
    void update(void Function(Settings input) adjustFunc) {
        adjustFunc(_settings);
        _settingsSaver.sink.add(_settings);
    }
}
```

So now you can do something like

```dart
var handler = SettingsHandler();
await handler.init();

// this
handler.data1Input.add('NewData');

// or this
handler.update((settings) {
    settings.someData1 = 'NewData';
});
```

Remember, this code only shows how the concept *can* work. You need to change it for your situation. You could also decide to not expose `data1Input` or the `update(...)` function, this is up to your own design.

<sup>1</sup> I personally use BloC, your situation might require a different way.